# Kill AsyncTask in Fragment Transaction

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I need some help.

I have this code to perform a transaction between two fragments:

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new EsamiFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
```

In both fragments i've got an asynctask. If I perform the transaction before the task has ended, it will throw an error. How to stop the task when I switch the fragment?
What i tried:

```
public void onDestroy ()
public void onStop ()
```

But they didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please explain why you have async task and fragment transactions so coupled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep a refrence to the `AyncTask` say `task`. in `onPause()` call `task.cancel()`
or before calling `transaction.commit()` call `task.cancel()`